# Is it possible to change a template to a HTML Email in content builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

I created templates when I meant to create HTML emails. Can I convert these templates into HTML emails inside of content builder within Marketing Cloud?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no function to convert email templates to email messages within Content Builder. Your easiest resolution to avoid rework would probably be to [create the email messages](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ceb_create_emails.htm&type=5), select the *Template* creation method, then choose your saved templates.